# Comma separating a list of dictionary items using jinja template

Tags: python, loops, flask, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries that needs to be comma-separated except for last item.
For eg list of dictionaries should be something like this:

**education_details**: `[{degree: "B.S.", type: "Full-type", location:"aus",grade:"A"}, {degree: "MCA", type: "Full-type", location:"aus",grade:"B"}]`

I was rendering the above details(education_details) in my jinja template like below:

```
{% for data in profile.get('education_details', []) %}
  {% if data.get('degree', '') %}
    {% if not loop.last %}
       <span>{{data.get('degree', '')}},</span>
    {% else %}
       <span>{{data.get('degree', '')}}</span>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if data.get('type', '') %}
    {% if not loop.last %}
       <span>{{data.get('type', '')}},</span>
    {% else %}
       <span>{{data.get('type', '')}}</span>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if data.get('location', '') %}
    {% if not loop.last %}
       <span>{{data.get('location', '')}},</span>
    {% else %}
       <span>{{data.get('location', '')}}</span>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried by using **last**, it's not working

**Expected o/p:**

**Commas to appear after each field except for the last entered item**

```
degree
degree, type, location
degree, location
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data and expected o/p, I assume you want the output like this:

```
B.S., Full-type, aus 
MCA, Full-type, aus
```

If this is the case, what you want is to print each list item row by row and to print each dictionary item's value one by one separated by `,` except last value.

If so, there is no need to use `loop.last` at all, instead, you just need to check the sequence of each dictionary key. Below is the code snippet (flask + jinja2) for that:

```
    template = """
{% for data in profile.get('education_details', []) %}

  {% if data.get('degree', '') %}
       <span>{{data.get('degree', '')}},</span>
  {% endif %}

  {% if data.get('type', '') %}
       <span>{{data.get('type', '')}},</span>
  {% endif %}

  {% if data.get('location', '') %}
       <span>{{data.get('location', '')}}</span>
  {% endif %}

  <br/>

{% endfor %}

    """
    education_details = [{"degree": "B.S.", "type": "Full-type", "location":"aus","grade":"A"},
                         {"degree": "MCA", "type": "Full-type", "location":"aus","grade":"B"}]

    return render_template_string(template, profile={"education_details": education_details})
```

Answer (score 0):

template:

```
{%- set listkeys = ['degree', 'type', 'location'] %}
{%- for data in profile.get('education_details', []) %}
  {%- set nbr = namespace(value=0) %}
  {%- for k in listkeys %}
  {%- if data.get(k, '') %}{%- set nbr.value = nbr.value + 1 %}{%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  {%- for k in listkeys %}
    {%- if data.get(k, '') %}
        {%- set nbr.value = nbr.value - 1 %}
            {%- if nbr.value > 0 %}
                <span>{{data.get(k, '')}},</span>
            {%- else %}
                <span>{{data.get(k, '')}}</span>
            {%- endif %}       
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  <br/>
{%- endfor %}
```

playtest:

```
education_details = [{"degree": "B.S.", "location":"aus","grade":"A"},
                     {"degree": "B.S."},
                     {"degree": "B.S.","grade":"A"},
                     {"degree": "B.S.", "type": "Full-type","grade":"A"},
                     {"type": "Full-type", "grade": "A"},
                     {"degree": "MCA", "type": "Full-type", "location":"aus","grade":"B"}]
```

result:

```
                <span>B.S.,</span>
                <span>aus</span>
  <br/>
                <span>B.S.</span>
  <br/>
                <span>B.S.</span>
  <br/>
                <span>B.S.,</span>
                <span>Full-type</span>
  <br/>
                <span>Full-type</span>
  <br/>
                <span>MCA,</span>
                <span>Full-type,</span>
                <span>aus</span>
  <br/>
```

**EDIT**
template without `namespace`:

```
{%- set listkeys = ['degree', 'type', 'location'] %}
{%- for data in profile.get('education_details', []) %}
  {%- set nbr = {'value': 0} %} 
  {%- for k in listkeys %}
  {%- if data.get(k, '') %}{%- set _ = nbr.update({'value': nbr.value + 1}) %}{%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  {%- for k in listkeys %}
    {%- if data.get(k, '') %}
        {%-  set _ = nbr.update({'value': nbr.value - 1}) %}
            {%- if nbr.value > 0 %}
                <span>{{data.get(k, '')}},</span>
            {%- else %}
                <span>{{data.get(k, '')}}</span>
            {%- endif %}       
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  <br/>
{%- endfor %}
```

you could use macro:

```
{%- macro inc(dct, key, inc=1) -%}
    {%- if dct.update({key: dct[key] + inc}) %}{%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}

{%- set listkeys = ['degree', 'type', 'location'] %}
{%- for data in profile.get('education_details', []) %}
  {%- set nbr = {'value': 0} %} 
  {%- for k in listkeys %}
  {%- if data.get(k, '') -%}{{ inc(nbr, 'value', 1) }}{%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  {%- for k in listkeys %}
    {%- if data.get(k, '') -%}
        {{ inc(nbr, 'value', -1) }}
            {%- if nbr.value > 0 %}
                <span>{{data.get(k, '')}},</span>
            {%- else %}
                <span>{{data.get(k, '')}}</span>
            {%- endif %}       
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  <br/>
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Getting NameError: name 'namespace' is not defined(I am using 3.6)

Comment: i think its not linked with version of python, but jinja2.. if namespace is not functional i fix may answer with other solution